# SQL Server view takes a long time to alter but query itself finishes quickly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to alter an existing view in my SQL Server database.  When I run the query by itself it finishes in about 4 seconds.  When I run the alter statement with the same query it runs and never finishes (waited 15 minutes before stopping it).

I do not have any indexes on the view I am trying to alter.  Any ideas what would cause something like this to happen?  Is there something I should be doing differently to speed things up?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure there's no contention for that view.  If something else is accessing it, or if there's a spid somewhere that's idle but has a connection to it, you may be blocked from the `ALTER` statement.

A simple `sp_who2 active` during the `ALTER` should give you the culprit.

Comment: Yep that was it.  Found the locking process and was able to resolve the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @Abe - HTH.  Happens to me a LOT when I'm trying to optimize things.

Answer (score 2):

I am too late for a response but I got the same issue. I just used kill (`spid`) for current query editor and then closed ssms and open it again and it is working fine for me.